# Domino and Tromino Combined Tiling

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, tiling

If I have a nx2 grid which I need to fill using 2x1 dominoes and L shaped trominoes in any combination, how many different combinations are possible?

I am aware that when only 2x1 dominoes are used then the cell definition using dynamic programming is:
$$
f\left [ 0 \right ]= 0
$$
$$
f\left [ 1 \right ]= 1, i=1
$$
$$
f\left [ 2 \right ]= 2, i=2
$$
$$
f\left [ i \right ]= f\left [ i-2 \right ]+ f\left [ i-1 \right ], \forall i>2
$$

When L shaped trominoes are added to consideration, we (assume) can use them only in pairs since using odd number L shaped trominoes will leave one 1x1 grid unfilled. so when a pair of such trominoes combine it is equivalent to using a single 3x2 rectangular piece. Everytime we use $\ num=\lfloor n/3 \rfloor $ rectangular pieces and the rest are filled with 2x1 dominoes. Also the total number of combinations would be sum of twice the $\ num$, $\ f[i] $ and number of 2x1 domino combinations of the rest of the grid when the 3x2 piece is used. Is this assumption right? This is how far I have gotten through. If any of you have any hints it would be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Note: Tile Rotations are allowed

Comment: You can use the same essence in the prototypical domino-tiling case. I'm not quite sure what the proper terminology is, but I'll use the term "irreducible" block to mean a block of dominoes that can't be vertically decomposed. So there's a single $2 \times 1$ irreducible block (just a domino lying flat), a single $2 \times 2$ block (two dominoes placed next to each other vertically), a single $2 \times 4$ block (two trominos placed together), and two $2 \times 3$ blocks (the two rotations of the do/tromino combo). Following the same intuition, you should be able to derive a similar recurrence.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I follow. When two trominos are placed isnt the block a $\ 2 \times 3 $ block?

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I accidentally visualized a tromino as a tall L shaped tile with 4 cells rather than a 3-celled corner. In this case, the situation is a bit more complicated. For example, you can construct an arbitrarily tall irreducible block of odd or even height. I'll elaborate on this later, but you should find that the $2 \times 3$ block can generalize to any $2 \times \rm odd$ blocks, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant information in the question itself.  Don't just leave clarifications in the comments -- we want the question to stand on its own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: This is a leetcode question with Solutions link at https://leetcode.com/problems/domino-and-tromino-tiling/solutions/
But overrall, it relies on the pattern found: f(n) = 2f(n−1)+f(n−3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mutual recursion in two variables $f(n)$  for the $n\times 2$ grid and $g(n)$ for the $n\times 2$ grid with a single square sticking out. It does not matter where the square sticks out (first or second row) because their number of tilings is the same.

[image: domino and tromino]

Note the trominos indeed come in pairs, but they do not need to form a $3\times 2$ block. You can place horizontal dominoes in between. Now that I look at it, it seems there is a recursion with one $f(n)$ if you look at a tromino and its matching partner. This picture suggests $f(7) = f(6)+f(5)+2f(4)+2f(3)+ \dots +2f(1)+2f(0)$. Sounds like a promising recursion to me.

[image]

If my initial computations are right, this suggests 1,1,2,5,11,24,53,117, ... which is [OEISA052980](http://oeis.org/A052980). This lists another recurrence however. Would be fun if they match.

PS. Yes! Recursions are the same.
$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 2\sum_{k=0}^{n-3} f(k)$. Then subtract $f(n)-f(n-1) = f(n-1)+f(n-3)$. Thus $f(n) = 2f(n-1)+f(n-3)$, which is in the OEIS.